# Google Drive API: How to determine whether a file is native

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Using the Drive API, you can deal with both native Google files (documents, spreadsheets etc) and uploaded files. However, the treatment is a bit different in some cases (for instance downloading). Yet, there doesn't seem to be any way to easily differentiate between them.

Here is the result of a get request for a **native file**, with all fields enabled (except users and permissions):

```
"kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1p11o_hprkEWurBR5m9yMxewYq6ia7oGogLa2f1SuM",
 "name": "Chats",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "version": "135321",
 "webViewLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p11o_hprkEWurBR5m9yMxewYq6ia7oGogLa2f1SuM/edit?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_spreadsheet_list.png",
 "thumbnailLink": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1p11o_hprkEWurBR5m9yMxewYq6ia7oGogLa2f1SuM&v=8&s=AMedNnoAAAAAV0bR380Izz-7y8f03tmRvNNKdfTjnODp&sz=s220",
 "viewedByMe": true,
 "viewedByMeTime": "2016-04-15T13:03:59.387Z",
 "createdTime": "2016-04-15T12:44:30.139Z",
 "modifiedTime": "2016-04-15T13:03:59.387Z",
 "modifiedByMeTime": "2016-04-15T13:03:59.387Z",
 "shared": true,
 "ownedByMe": true,
 "viewersCanCopyContent": true,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
 "isAppAuthorized": false
}
```

Here is the result of a **non-native file:**

```
"kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0yUN_7RUIxZyVkYtUOeW9wbGc",
 "name": "ITcom presentation - CNR Debrecen.pptx",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "version": "135323",
 "webContentLink": "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0yUN_7RUIxZyVkYtUOeW9wbGc&export=download",
 "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0yUN_7RUIxZyVkYtUOeW9wbGc/view?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_powerpoint_list.png",
 "thumbnailLink": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p0LUsafMy3_Q7reWZ6jMnRGrQ51em7i9vWvgKp2jTkUdPQ8Ks9-S4bs6sk8DeZBFpqVYAw=s220",
 "viewedByMe": true,
 "viewedByMeTime": "2015-02-04T21:47:00.564Z",
 "createdTime": "2015-02-04T21:46:57.813Z",
 "modifiedTime": "2015-02-04T21:46:57.813Z",
 "modifiedByMeTime": "2015-02-04T21:46:57.813Z",
 "shared": true,
 "ownedByMe": true,
 "viewersCanCopyContent": true,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "originalFilename": "ITcom presentation - CNR Debrecen.pptx",
 "fullFileExtension": "pptx",
 "fileExtension": "pptx",
 "md5Checksum": "7a7977f8620e7f02f533f98254ae824b",
 "size": "1835994",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "1835994",
 "headRevisionId": "0yUN_7RUIxZyamN4bEp2WDlqNm4vUmR3YUdCdDVBb0Q3MDdnPQ",
 "isAppAuthorized": false
}
```

So there are differences, among them the mime type and the fact that a native file doesn't have fields such as size, extension, etc. But I'm not sure any of them is enough to positively identify a file as native. Thoughts?

Comment: mime type is the definitive mechanism. As a good proxy, the presence of absence of downloadUrl vs exportLinks will also work.

Comment: The thing that blocks me is that I don't necessarily know all the mimetypes that native files can take, and I'm afraid that if I try to check for the presence/absence of, say, "google-apps" in the type, there might be false positives (for instance other file types from google). I've been using size for now (seems to be null with native files), but maybe the ones you propose are better.